# Create new window in Woocommerce on click "Place Order Button"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment, gateway

now i using Woocommerce - wordpress for shopping mall
i'm sorry to my bad english but i need your help.

First, i want create new payment gateway. it done
 - After copy other payment gateway, paste my gateway's name in code

But i faced big problem.
 - I have no method to add

```
<script>window.open()</script>
```

code on Click "PLACE ORDER" button

below my source code

```
/* class.wc-gateway-mine.php */
if(!defined('ABSPATH')){
 exit;
}
//Description ..
class WC_gatewqy_mine extend WC_Payment_Gatewqy{

 //function __construct()..
 //function init_form_fields()..
 //function thankyou_page()..
 //function email_instructions()..

 function process_payment($order_id){

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    /* I want add new Javascript code here for create new window.
       After that child window submit "success" value to parent(or Parent window received "success" value from child window),
       I hope that the following processes will proceed as well(payment_process).
     */

    // Mark as processing (we're awaiting the cinfirm checkout)
    $order->update_status( 'processing', _x( 'Awaiting check payment', 'Check payment method', 'woocommerce' ) );

    // Reduce stock levels
    $order->reduce_order_stock();

    // Remove cart
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();

    // Return thankyou redirect
    return array(
        'result'    => 'success',
        'redirect'  => $this->get_return_url( $order )
    );


 }
}
```

how can i do?